# Getting error while using sparkDataset to write to S3: Class org.apache.spark.internal.io.cloud.BindingParquetOutputCommitter not found

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-dataset

**I get this error when using sparkDataset to write to S3:**

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.spark.internal.io.cloud.BindingParquetOutputCommitter not found

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the matching spark-hadoop-cloud jar from your spark release into the spark classpath, that's where the class lives